# Azure DevOps 2019.1 (On-Prem) Who are the "Azure DevOps Server Administrator" on the "Provide Scheduled Backups Alert Settings"

Tags: azure-devops

I am doing backups and setup the alert on "Schedule Backups Wizard"
It says

> Send email to Azure DevOps Server Administrator if a backup job fails

When backup is failing all the "Administrator Console Users" are getting notified, but I have a bunch of other people also getting notified.

Are the "Azure DevOps Server Administrator" anyone who has Admin rights over the server? If yes can I tell the system who to e-mail?

I guess my main question is "Who are the Azure DevOps Server Administrators"?

Update1:
Is there a way to manually edit the list of people who gets e-mailed?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please check if Krzystof's answer helps to resolve your issue.